# Add dragging in a resizable div in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, resize, draggable, aspect-ratio

I've got a resizable div in which i have to keep the aspect ratio. What i have to do now is implement the dragging functionality. This is what i've done so far

https://stackblitz.com/edit/icon-font-awesome-h3mzgc?file=src/app/app.component.ts

I can drag it, i can also resize it but it doesn't work very well.
First of all, it grows only in height and width. Second, it grows px by px not following the mouse movement. I've tried to use this part of code for the dragging part and also for part of the resize

https://github.com/theideasaler/angular-resizable-draggable/blob/master/src/app/resizable-draggable/resizable-draggable.component.ts

the drag function is this one

```
dragEvent(event: MouseEvent, status: number) {
    console.log(event, status)
    if(status === 1) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    } else if(status === 2) {
      this.mouseClick = { x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY, left: this.left, top: this.top };
    } else {
      this.loadBox()
    };

    this.status = status;
  }
```

and i've tried to use the mousemove listener in this way

```
@HostListener('window:mousemove', ['$event'])
  onMouseMove(event: MouseEvent){
    this.mouse = { x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY };

    if(this.status === Status.RESIZE) this.resize(event);
    else if(this.status === Status.MOVE) this.move();
  }

  private resize(e){
    if(this.resizeCondMeet()){
      let pageX;
      const diff = isNaN(pageX) ? 1 : e.pageX - pageX;
        const minSize = 10;

        if (
          (this.width + diff < minSize || this.height + diff < minSize) &&
          diff < 0
        ) {
          return;
        }

        this.width = this.width + diff;
        this.height = this.height + diff;

        pageX = e.pageX;
    }
  }
```

But it's not working. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

the solution is store, when startDrag, the position of the mouse the with and the height

```
  dragEvent(event: MouseEvent, status: number) {
    if(status === 1) {
      this.init={x:event.pageX,width:this.width,height:this.height}
      event.stopPropagation();
    } else if(status === 2) {
        ....
    }
  }
```

Then, when move use this variable

```
  private resize(e) {
    if (this.resizeCondMeet()) {
      const newWidth = this.init.width + e.pageX - this.init.x;
      const newHeight = this.init.height + e.pageX - this.init.x;
      const minSize = 10;

      if (newWidth < minSize || newHeight < minSize) return;

      this.width = newWidth;
      this.height = newHeight;
    }
  }
```